# SELECT DISTINCT but use COUNT too

Tags: mysql

i have this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT brand FROM table ORDER BY brand ASC
```

How can i extend this query to get the amount of the single brands too?

It should look like this:

```
Audi (38)
Ford (10)
Tesla (6)
Toyota (29)
```

The query must be something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT brand, COUNT(brand) AS amount FROM table ORDER BY brand ASC
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just select brand, count(brand) as amount from table group by brand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` instead of `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT brand, COUNT(brand) AS amount FROM table GROUP BY brand ORDER BY brand ASC
```